# Causal inference for a trained Gradient Boosting of decision trees

Tags: machine-learning, inference, causality

I am quite new to the space, but I was wondering if it was possible to do causal analysis with a model trained with Gradient Boosting of decision trees?

I know there are packages like causalnex, https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/causalnex, but it does not seem to support gradient boosting, as it is a completely different framework.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For gradient boosting I am assuming you mean gradient boosting a linear model.  The issue with this is that you are 'regularizing' your coefficients. So essentially you shrink them.  Causal interpretation of regularized coefficients from a traditional POV is pretty controversial for well defined regularization techniques like LASSO and Ridge and I have not heard of any efforts to do it with boosting.  Most practitioners would just do Ridge from a bayesian perspective and I would assume the model would be fairly similar or better performing than the boosted one.

With that said, it is *possible* to carry around the coefficients and standard errors and adjust them after each boosting round by simply adding the coefficients and updating your standard error.  This will get you a p-value in the end but I doubt it is technically correct.

Some [old code](https://github.com/tblume1992/LazyProphet) I have actually does this in a time-series setting where I combine decomposition (splitting a time series into trend + seasonality + extra factors) with boosting and I provide a normal ols summary for the extra factors if given. See the 'Dealing with Exogenous Variables' section to see this:
[image]

But like I said, if you want to use regularization I would just stick with Ridge and go from there.

Comment: Thanks @Tylerr for the answer. What about for a causal model of gradient boosting of decision trees?

Comment: You could look at BART: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BART/BART.pdf .

Comment: thanks a lot !!